# Why am I getting NullPointerException when running this code?

Tags: java, input, nullpointerexception, char

Whyam I getting a NullPointerException when running this code, I have looked up what it is and still don't understand how to fix it; help please?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        String User = sc.nextLine();
        char [] pass = System.console().readPassword();
        System.out.println(pass);
        char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(c);
        char d = sc.findInLine("a").charAt(0);
        System.out.println(d);
        char b = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(User);
} 
}
```

When running the code everything runs fine up until the last two lines using the variable `char b` The error outputted is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

Comment: What is "sc" and how did you make sure it has two "."?

Comment: because `sc.next(".")` returns `null`.

Comment: Line 33 is `char d = sc.findInLine(".").charAt(0);`

Comment: Looks like `sc.findInLine(".")` returns `null`.

Comment: @Andy what arguments can I use to find a specific character from a scanner? I've tried replacing `"."` with a letter which is present and it still gives the `NullPointerException`

Comment: @user3719657 regex and capturing groups?

Comment: You can't expect to be told what goes wrong without showing the input you use for testing. mick\nsecret\nall ball code\n does not throw an exception, but mick\nsecret\nall xxx yyy does. --- It's extremely bad to write code that depends on the input being "correct".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        String User = sc.nextLine();
        char [] pass = System.console().readPassword();
        System.out.println(pass);
        char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(c);
        String d = sc.next();
        boolean Contained;
        if(d.contains("a")){
           Contained = true;
        }
        else{ Contained = false; }
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println("Contains a ? " + Contained); 
        char b = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(User);
} 
}
```

This will still check whether that character `a` is in the String although will return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `sc.findInLine(".")` returns null here. As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine%28java.lang.String%29),

```
If no such pattern is detected in the input up to the next line separator, 
then null is returned and the scanner's position is unchanged.
```

Also, when you pass a String pattern to findInLine, it eventually behaves like `findInLine(Pattern.compile(pattern))`.

Answer (score 0):

Tho' the entire class is not included in your code segment, I feeling following might be the problematic area

1. you might forgot to set x in *System.out.println(x);*
2. There might not be any "." in you *sc* object and as a result `sc.next(".")` returns `null`

The `NullPointerException` is thrown in Java application when you try to use a null object. The error occurs as you try to call instance method of an object which is null. For example, you have an Object `sc.next(".")` returning you a null object and you are trying to access `charAt(0)` method using this object.

If you have still some confusion, plz post your entire class